# A question about distribution $|x|^{-2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Define $|x|^{-2}$ be the linear functional on $C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R})$ which is defined as :

$$\phi\mapsto\int_{\Bbb{R}_+}\left(x^{-2}(\phi(x) + \phi(-x) - 2\phi(0))\right)dx$$

I have a question for this definition,it seems this linear functional is only well defined for test function $\phi(0) = 0$ only due to the last constant term and singularity  $x^{-2}$ at origin.Why it's well defined linear functional for all test function? which makes it $C_c^\infty \to \Bbb{R}$ maps into?

Comment: Taylor's Theorem shows that $|\phi(x)+\phi(-x)-2\phi(0)|\le cx^2$.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich thanks, do you mean we can't see it separately?

Comment: I have no idea what "can't see it separately" means.

Comment: I mean should not integrate term by term then sum them up but treat $|\phi(x)+\phi(-x)-2\phi(0)|$ as a single expression.That's not important ,thanks

Comment: The image of $\phi$ is invariant under adding an odd or constant function in $C_c^\infty(\Bbb R)$ to $\phi$, so this functional is often well-defined. On the other hand, $x^2$ is mapped to $\int_0^\infty2dx=\infty$.

Comment: right - the integrals of the individual terms do not converge.

Comment: nice observation.